# WhatsApp voice call bug: not able to be heard when app is in the background

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, audio, calls, voice

I have a Pixel 7 and am fully up to date with any software updates and WhatsApp version. Recently, I have been having an issue with WhatsApp audio/voice calls. During the call, if I try going to the home or lock screen or even opening another app for some reason if I talk, the other end isn't able to hear me. For the other line to hear me speaking on the phone, I need WhatsApp to be opened and for me to be on the WhatsApp screen. Once I leave the app or my phone goes to lock screen, I can still hear them perfectly fine, just I seemingly lose the ability to talk for them to hear me.

I have no idea what the issue is, I've tried clearing the cache and restarting my phone, this problem has already been for a month or two.

Does anyone have any suggestions/ideas?